# How to drop a fixed number of labelled rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a huge class imbalance. So I want to downsample the majority label (let's call this label 1) to a fixed number. Let's say I have 1000 label 1s, and I want the dataframe to drop 500 label 1s, how can I do that?

Comment: 1. Get all rows where (label != 1)  
2. Get all rows where (label == 1)  
3. Take first (or random) 500 from (2)  
4. Put result of 1 and 3 in a new Dataframe

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is assigned to `df`: `df.drop(df[df.label == 1].sample(500).index)`. It would be easier to answer your question if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code that will drop 50% of `label == 1`. you can decide how you want to calculate your `n_to_drop`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 3, size=(10,2)),
                  columns=['Label', 'Other_Col'])


label_1 = df[df['Label'] == 1]
n_to_drop = label_1.shape[0]//2
index_to_drop = label_1.sample(n_to_drop).index
dropped_df = df.drop(index_to_drop)

print(df)
print(dropped_df)


   Label  Other_Col
0      1          2
1      1          2
2      2          1
3      1          1
4      2          1
5      1          2
6      2          1
7      2          2
8      1          1
9      2          2

   Label  Other_Col
0      1          2
2      2          1
3      1          1
4      2          1
6      2          1
7      2          2
8      1          1
9      2          2
```

Comment: This is very neat. Thank you!